# Partially load tf.contrib.learn.Estimators from model_dir (load only decoder weights in auto-encoder setup)

Tags: tensorflow, autoencoder

I'm trying to work with `Estimators` rather than implementing training loops on my own. I'm playing with an auto-encoder on MNIST data. I have a `training_model_fn` function to build a training model that includes the inputs, model, loss, optimizers and summaries. I can train it and everything goes well, but when I'm trying to load only the decoder part - it fails.

I want the decoder model to get the `encoded` vector as input, and run through the same decoding part of the network (with the previously learnt weights) to generate the `decoded` image at the end.

I've created another `decoded_model_fn` function that share some code with the training one and creates only the relevant part of the model, but when I'm trying to load the `Estimator` with:

```
est = tf.contrib.learn.Estimator(model_fn=decoder_model_fn, model_dir=...)
est.predict(input_fn=...)
```

I get the following error:

```
...    
NotFoundError: Key ... not found in checkpoint ...
...
```

I assume that `Estimator` is trying to load all variables from the checkpoint and obviously my decoder model doesn't contain all of them.

Does anyone know how I can partially load variables from a stored session? I would expect a `ignore_unknowns` flag but couldn't find anything similar.

Any example of how I'm supposed to use `Estimator` for auto-encoder models?

Answer (score 0):

OK... answering myself in case anyone gets to this in the future:

The primary problem in my case was that I mistakenly didn't put the decoder in the same `variable_scope` as in the large model. Variables weren't called in the same name and therefore failed to load.

Another thing that happened to me, and might cause problems - when I trained the original model I fed it with numpy arrays that I made sure to cast to `float32`so weights were stored as `float32`. When I fed the decoder model, I used some dummy np arrays and they were `float64` so tensorflow complained that it expects more data than it has in the checkpoint data. Took me some time to figure out why that was happening...